# What language is used to manipulate variables?

Tags: variables, jasper-reports, conditional-statements

I am new to *JasperReports*, using *iReport v. 4*, and having a hard time for instance creating conditional expressions with variables and fields within text fields in my reports because I dont know what programming language shall I use?

Ex: `($F{}==null || $F{}.equals(""))?"N/A":$F{}...`

But it doesn't work? What language shall I use: Java? no, It doesn't seem really like *Java*. Groovy? I checked it on the web, it looks different. What are we talking about here? so I can get my self some documentation and be able to manipulate conditions easily and freely. Or if you can point me to some documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Expression used by JasperReports are written in Java-like Groovy style. It means that basically they are Java expression, but with some additional syntax made possible with from Groovy, to reference different kind of objects (parameters, fields, variables). 
From the code snippet provided by you, `($F{}==null || $F{}.equals(""))?"N/A":$F{}` i can say that you just have to learn this last part (i mean, how does the reference work).
The `$F{}` expression, means that you are referencing to a ***Field***, but you need to specify which one. For example: `$F{TITLE}`, which means you are trying to get the value of the ***Title*** field/attribute from you data source. 
Please refer to these links to have a clear idea: 
1. [Expressions](http://www.jasperassistant.com/docs/guide/ch06.html)
2. [Examples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_expression.htm)
3. [Default language for expressions](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-designer-groovy)

Comment: Thanks! especially for the links.
I will eventually learn by my mistakes and will keep trying syntaxes till I cover most cases.